# How to retrieve comments with Camel and XPath

Tags: java, xpath, apache-camel

I defined a route that consumes an XML message from a JMS queue. The processing is just the extraction of the comment and log it.

```
    from("jms:so")
            .setHeader("comment").xpath("//comment()", String.class)
            .setHeader("firstComment").xpath("//comment()[1]", String.class)
            .log("comment is ${headers.comment}")
            .log("first comment is ${headers.firstComment}")
            .to("jms:so.out");
```

The message is simple:

```
<StackOverflow>
    <!--Camel-->
    <Nested>
    <!--Nested Camel-->
    </Nested>
</StackOverflow>
```

The issue is that the comment values are not extracted.

Comment: Tested it local and think problem is in type converter. When xpath evaluating value it converting body to Document and after that i can't see any comments. Try to use custom type converter as workaround.

Comment: Yeah the xml parser is optimized to skip comments (or it does not do that by default). Its very unusual to use comments in XML for any business purpose. What is your use-case for needing to read xml comments?